# pandas, groupby.agg to return with a given column name

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I do

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].agg({'total' : np.sum})
```

so that the aggregated column has a column name `total`. But recently I get a warning

```
FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
```

So what is the preferred way now?

Comment: I would simply rename the column afterwards: `.rename(columns={'B': 'total'})`.

Comment: `df.groupby('A').agg({'B' : np.sum}).rename(columns={'B': 'total'})` OR `df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(np.sum).to_frame('total')` would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `rename` or define `name` parameter in [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

Check also [deprecate groupby agg with a dictionary when renaming](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming).

**1.**

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].sum().reset_index(name='total')
```

**2.**

```
df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].sum().rename(columns={'B':'total'})
```

**3.**

```
df = df.groupby('A').agg({'B' : 'sum'}).rename(columns={'B':'total'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: I think the column is named `B` but the OP wants it called `total` in the result.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ways

```
In [57]: df.groupby('A')['B'].sum().to_frame('total')
Out[57]:
   total
A
a      2
b      1

In [58]: df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(np.sum).to_frame('total')   # or agg('sum')
Out[58]:
   total
A
a      2
b      1

In [59]: df.groupby('A').agg({'B': np.sum}).rename(columns={'B': 'total'})
Out[59]:
   total
A
a      2
b      1
```